# Fractional Brownian motion of Riemann-Liouville type is not a semimartingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Given a filtered probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{F},\mathbb{P})$ satisfying the usual conditions, $B$ a standard one-dimensional Brownian motion and $H\in(0,1/2)$. Consider the process $X$ given by
$$
X_t = \int_0^t \frac{(t-s)^{H-1/2}}{\Gamma(H+1/2)} d B_s,
$$
where $\Gamma$ denotes the gamma function.
The process $X$ is called fractional Brownian motion of Riemann-Liouville type with Hurst parameter $H.$ I have read in various articles that it is well-known that $X$ is not a semimartingale. I am trying to understand why this statement is true. However, I find it difficult to show this. I tried approximating the non-differentiable kernel $K(t)=\frac{t^{H-1/2}}{\Gamma(H+1/2)}$ by continuously differentiable kernels, $\varepsilon>0,$
$$
K_\varepsilon(t)= \frac{(t+\varepsilon)^{H-1/2}}{\Gamma(H+1/2)}.
$$
Then, an application of the stochastic Fubini theorem shows that
$$
X_t^\varepsilon = \int_0^t K_\varepsilon(t-s) dB_s
$$
is a semimartingale with quadratic variation $ \langle X^\varepsilon\rangle_t = K_\varepsilon(0)^2 t $ and $\langle X^\varepsilon\rangle_t\to\infty$ as $\varepsilon\downarrow0.$ Moreover, I was able to show that $\mathbb{E}(|X_t^\varepsilon-X_t|^2)\to0$ as $\varepsilon\downarrow0.$ Now, I aim to conclude that $\langle X\rangle_t=\infty$ which would yield the claim.

I would be grateful for any suggestion on how to finish my proof or any other way that shows the assertion.

Answer (score 2):

I see another way of finishing the proof. I think, we can begin to show that $\langle X,X\rangle_{1}=+\infty$ and by scaling argument, it will be proven for all $t$. We can use the quadratic variation approximation property which states that $\langle X,X\rangle_{1}$ can be approximated by
$$\underset{n\rightarrow +\infty}{\lim}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\lvert X(\frac{j}{n})-X(\frac{j-1}{n})\rvert^{2} $$
Then, using that $(a^{-H}X(at)\sim X(t))$, we have that the last expression has the same distribution that
$$\underset{n\rightarrow +\infty}{\lim}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\lvert X(j)-X(j-1)\rvert^{2} n^{-2H} $$
and, now we can apply ergodic theorem to state that
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\lvert X(j)-X(j-1)\rvert^{2}  $$ converges in $\mathbf{L}^{1}$ and a.s to $\mathbf{E}[\lvert X(1)\rvert^{2}]$, and since $1-2H>0$, we can conclude that the $\langle X,X\rangle_{t}=+\infty$.

Maybe, something silly, but have you tried to use  Burkholder-Davis-Gundy inequality to show that the quadratic variation was also going to $0$?

I hope it is clear enough!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Your proof works for the fBM introduced by Mandelbrot & van Ness. However, I am asking for a specific proof for the Riemann-Liouville fBM. I also asked this question [here] (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/446360/fractional-brownian-motion-of-riemann-liouville-type-is-not-a-semimartingale). There it was mentioned that the two notions are locally equivalent. With this ingredient, combined with your proof, one should be able to prove the claim.

Comment: I was also thinking about using the BDG inequality. However, we are not dealing with local martingales even $X^\varepsilon$ is just a semimartingale, we would need a special BDG inequality for semimartingales.